# jQuery prop('disabled') not working on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, disabled-input

I am trying to mark a radio button as disabled, which i have had success with before. But i have met a problem i don't understand, where the radio button won't set the `disabled` attribute, but will without problem set the `checked` attribute.

I am creating timeslots in a for-loop (based on data collected async) where i create the new timeslot doms through jQuery like so:

```
for(var key in aTimeslots){
    $timeslot = $('<div/>', {
        "class": "timeslot"
    });

    $timeslotLabel = $('<label/>');

    $timeslotRadio = $('<input />', {
        "type": "radio",
        "class": "timeslots",
        "name": "timeslotRadios"
    });


    // LOGIC TO CHECK IF THE TIMESLOT HAS BEEN RESERVED IS HERE

    // Glue shit together
    $timeslotLabel.append($timeslotRadio);
    $timeslot.append($timeslotLabel);

    // Add the timeslot to the DOM containing all the timeslots
    $availableTimeslots.append($timeslot);

    // Check if the timeslots is reserved
    if(bIsReservedDate){
        $timeslotRadio.prop('checked', true);
        $timeslotRadio.prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

As written above, i set the `checked` attribute to true, at this works without problem. But the `disabled` attribute will not be set. Do anyone have an idea why this is? I even moved the logic to after the DOMS have been added to the `$availableTimeslots`, which so i am sure the doms has been rendered.. but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: I think that putting an input `into/appended` to a `label` is not meant to be.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker It's fine. You can either wrap a label around the input or you can use the `for` attribute in the label to associate them.

Comment: set it to `disabled` ie `$timeslotRadio.prop('disabled', 'disabled');`

Comment: @Derek jQuery supports it either way.

Comment: the `disabled` property can have both values and they both mean different things. trust me.

Comment: Your code looks fine, OP. Can you setup a http://jsfiddle.net which replicates the problem. My guess is there is an error elsewhere which is causing this behaviour.

Comment: @Derek the `disabled` _attribute_ can have both values - the _property_ should only ever be a boolean.

Comment: OP - you need to use the `var` keyword somewhat more - you're polluting the global namespace at the moment (not that this is your problem, it's just sloppy coding).

Comment: Fiddle for you folks to have fun with http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/ypLa2mbq/

Comment: It seems to work correctly in the fiddle. All the radio buttons are disabled.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. When i try to make a jsfiddle everything works correctly, so i don't get this at all. http://jsfiddle.net/Thorap/hnvLqdd4/

Comment: What browser/version did your original code not work?

Comment: i use chrome, and it has to work in this browser. Also the Fiddle is tested in chrome and there it works.. It is really weird since i can set the checked attr without problems.

Comment: The weird thing is, I opened your fiddle in the latest Firefox and nothing happens. No elements are appended to the DOM...

Comment: Cant get it to work in firefox, but my focus is on chrome, so it has to work there first.